# Making artificial sweat

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

I'm currently working on a chemistry investigation wherein I need to dilute a compound with artificial sweat. I have looked at various forums, including [this](https://www.finishing.com/310/79.shtml), which gave answers, but is very outdated.

I have also checked on ISOs standards, but it seems that I cannot get the information I want - ISO 105-E04 - without paying a huge sum.

Do any of you know of a recipe for artificial sweat that I can easily conjure in a lab, that's also backed up by various sources?

Thanks

P.S. I *cannot* just use water + salt, as that would be too simple and cause too many uncertainties for my experiment.

Comment: Sweat is known to contain water, urea, and certain salts like NaCl. Try visiting Wikipedia page about sweat and get the exact composition.

Comment: ISO 105-E04 describes two solutions, an alkaline solution buffered to pH 8 and an acid solution buffered to pH 5.5. In addition to the phosphate buffer, both solutions contain sodium chloride and L-histidine. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Loong Yes. Unfortunately, it doesn't give the exact proportions of chemicals required to be mixed together unless you pay. In the link I put in my post, someone gave the composition of sweat from another ISO standard, but sadly it was from 2004.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Wikipedia offers the composition, but it doesn't state the concentrations of lactic acid or urea. However, it does go in a lot of depth for the less noticeable components, like the different metals.

Answer (score 4):

The international standard ISO 105-E01:2013 *Textiles* – *Tests for colour fastness* – Part E01: *Colour fastness to water* includes specifications for two different solutions:

**Alkaline solution,** freshly prepared, using grade 3 water complying with ISO 3696, containing, per litre:

- 0.5 g of ʟ-histidine monohydrochloride monohydrate ($\ce{C6H9O2N3.HCl.H2O}$);
- 5 g of sodium chloride ($\ce{NaCl}$);
  and either
- 5 g of disodium hydrogen orthophosphate dodecahydrate ($\ce{Na2HPO4.12H2O}$)
  or
- 2.5 g of disodium hydrogen orthophosphate dihydrate ($\ce{Na2HPO4.2H2O}$).

The solution is brought to pH 8 (± 0.2) with 0.1 mol/l sodium hydroxide solution.

**Acid solution,** freshly prepared, using grade 3 water complying with ISO 3696, containing, per litre:

- 0.5 g of ʟ-histidine monohydrochloride monohydrate ($\ce{C6H9O2N3.HCl.H2O}$);
- 5 g of sodium chloride ($\ce{NaCl}$);
- 2.2 g of sodium dihydrogen orthophosphate dihydrate ($\ce{NaH2PO4.2H2O}$).

The solution is brought to pH 5.5 (± 0.2) with 0.1 mol/l sodium hydroxide solution.